# Microsoft Store API : AppSubmissionUpdateSample.cs function calls works in Console App but not in UWP

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, windows-store-apps

Documentation and samples are available here [ [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/csharp-code-examples-for-the-windows-store-submission-api) ]

AppSubmissionUpdateSample.cs is a popular sample code from microsoft store api. In my experiment i found that sample code work fine in C# console app, but not in C# UWP App.

eg.

```
In C# Console APP
       // Get authorization token
                Console.WriteLine("Getting authorization token ");
                var accessToken = IngestionClient.GetClientCredentialAccessToken(
                    tokenEndpoint,
                    clientId,
                    clientSecret,
                    resourceOrScope).Result;
```

Above line works and fetches the results. but the same line of code, makes the application hang in C# UWP.

As a workaround i tried to rewrite the code in following way in C# UWP app, it then works, but i have no understanding why i am forced to use async/await, if anybody can explain to make me understand what's going on.

```
 In C# UWP App
     // Get authorization token
                Console.WriteLine("Getting authorization token ");
                var accessTokenX = IngestionClient.GetClientCredentialAccessToken(
                    tokenEndpoint,
                    clientId,
                    clientSecret,
                    resourceOrScope);
                var accessToken = await accessTokenX;    <----- forced to use async/await to work in UWP
```

Can anyone thow some light please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Derive from document: [Asynchronous programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/threading-async/asynchronous-programming-universal-windows-platform-apps)

Each programming language supports the asynchronous pattern for the UWP in its own way:

[image]

Comment: Hi Dasiy, my question is why the same line of code cannot work?  i am not changing language here, just copy pasting code from C# console app to C# UWP app;  my C# console app does not use any asynchonous method, so why i am forced to use asynchronous when code is copied in C# UWP app;?

Comment: The table is for UWP ,so if you want to use UWP with C# language , you are forced to use keyword async/await.